# TimescaleDB query to get data for boolean or step function without averaging

Tags: timescaledb

I want to store data for a voltage switch, so the voltage is either 12 or 0. If I use timebuckets for averaging, then I will get values like 6 etc, which doesn't make sense for the user and I don't want that. If I don't use timebuckets, then I can't reduce the data points. Otherwise I will fetch so much data points in my query. So how can I reduce data points same as timebuckets, but also receive only 2 values (either 12 or 0) like a step graph?

Comment: Any reason not to save it as a boolean? 

Have you checked the [downsampling](https://www.timescale.com/blog/a-different-and-often-better-way-to-downsample-your-prometheus-metrics/) techniques?

Here you can see an [example](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/user-defined-actions/example-downsample-and-compress/#downsample-and-compress).

Comment: It could have like more steps. like either 0, 6, 10 or 12. So it is like a step function, not just boolean